# Get href of dynamically created bound link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some links that are dynamically created within a table and the `href` of those links sends a `GET` request to delete a user. I have the listener bound like so:

```
var $usersTableBody = $('#table-users tbody');
var $deleteUserBtn = $('.delete-user-btn');
$usersTableBody.on('click', $deleteUserBtn, deleteConfirm);
```

I need to get the `href` of `$deleteUserBtn`, the problem is that now I cannot get the link of the `<a>` that I am clicking since the event is bound to the table body. So... how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Add a `click` event to `.delete-user-btn` , use `event.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: You're passing a jQuery object as the second argument to `.on()`. Is that even supported? If you passed the selector instead, then you'd just use `this` in the handler to refer to the clicked `<a>`.

Comment: @guest271314 It's a dynamically created element so I am having to bind the event with event delegation like I am doing above.

Comment: @squint *"Is that even supported?"* ~ not according to the docs. The *selector* argument should be a string

Comment: @Phil: That's what I thought. Surprised it doesn't throw an error or something.

Comment: @squint it's probably just being applied as a string in which case it would come out as `"[object Object]"`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ Scroll down to the first code snippets. It is supported. All it is, is a variable for an element in the DOM.

Comment: @DCTC What is expected result ?

Comment: DC TC: That's `.delegate()` and it doesn't show a jQuery object being allowed. jQuery's version of event delegation requires a selector (like the `'.delete-user-btn'` string). You're passing a jQuery object.

Comment: @DCTC no, the `selector` argument is *"Type: String"*, not *"Type: jQuery"*

Comment: @guest271314 Trying to get the href of the clicked element. NOTE: `$(this).attr('href')` does not work because `$(this)` is in the context of the table's `tbody`.

Comment: @DCTC: You're just not listening, are you.

Comment: Is `.delete-user-btn` an `a` element ?

Comment: @squint Yep. I'm listening. I did not notice that I could only pass a string and not a DOM element. I was typing when you replied last, so.... calm down a little ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making it easy for you

```
//                                  this argument should be a string
//                                  ↓
$('#table-users tbody').on('click', '.delete-user-btn', function(e) {
    alert(this.href); // "this" is the event target / source
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

> **selector**
>   Type: **String**
>   A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("click", "a.delete-user-btn", function(event) {
  // prevent default action, to not affect any other 
  // event handlers attached to `a.delete-user-btn`
  event.preventDefault();
  // do stuff with `this` : `a.delete-user-btn` `href` property
  console.log(this.href)
})
```

Comment: Setting the `document` as the delegate listener might be too broad for what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

First, please see the documentation for jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because you are not using the correct parameters.

I don't know the exact nature of your HTML, but you can use the target property of the event callback object to determine the href:

```
$usersTableBody.on('click', function(e) {
    var $target = jQuery(e.target);
    alert('clicked: ' + $target.attr('href'));
    deleteConfirm();

    // delete action
});
```

See this jsbin for another example: https://jsbin.com/huzegufihe/edit?html,output